# Issues uploading to atmega324pb w/ adruino as ISP

Tags: uploading, avrdude, isp

I've been having some issues programming a new atmega324pb I have on a custom board. I set up an old adruino UNO as an ISP by uploading the ArduinoISP sketch, setting the programmer to "Arduino as ISP" and then using the "Upload using programmer" option but to no avail. Here is the verbose error message that the console logs:

```
System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM5
     Using Programmer              : stk500v1
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
     AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
     Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
     PAGEL                         : PD7
     BS2                           : PA0
     RESET disposition             : dedicated
     RETRY pulse                   : SCK
     serial program mode           : yes
     parallel program mode         : yes
     Timeout                       : 200
     StabDelay                     : 100
     CmdexeDelay                   : 25
     SyncLoops                     : 32
     ByteDelay                     : 0
     PollIndex                     : 3
     PollValue                     : 0x53
     Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : STK500
     Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
     Hardware Version: 2
     Firmware Version: 1.18
     Topcard         : Unknown
     Vtarget         : 0.0 V
     Varef           : 0.0 V
     Oscillator      : Off
     SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)
```

I think it might be an issue with Arduino possibly targeting a chip other than atmega324pb that I'm using, but I'm not sure. I don't know of any official arduino boards that utilize the 324pb. The main issue that I see is that avrdude can't find the device signature. I've see others mention it might be faulty wiring, but I made sure all connections are intact.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange.  Please take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site, and to see how to attract the most useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering, I solved the problem.
Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out how to upload it using Arduino as ISP, but I was able to get it to work with an [AVR Pocket Programmer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825) from Sparkfun. If you decide to use this, check out [this drivers guide.](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pocket-avr-programmer-hookup-guide#installing-drivers) It will It'll save massive headache getting the usb device to be recognized.

**IMPORTANT FOR ATMEGA324PB USERS!!!**
The atmega324pb is apparently not a default microcontroller in avrdude. You need to add it to the toolchain manually. You can do this by following this blog:
https://hackaday.io/project/9313-uino-mini-super-atmega328pb/log/31003-easy-way-to-a-toolchain-for-the-atmega328pb
It is the same process to add any Microchip microcontroller to avrdude, so this guide will work for the atmega324pb (did it firsthand). From there, you can also add a custom entry to Arduino's boards.txt config file if you'd like to use the Arduino IDE for development. I didn't mind working the command line, but having it in Arduino definitely streamlines the proccess of compiling the .hex and uploading it in one go.

Here is the custom entry I added to Arduino's boards.txt file for the Atmega324pb. All the data was gathered from the datasheet:

```
####   ATmega324PB    ####
m324p.name=Atmega324pb
m324p.upload.via_ssh=true

m324p.vid.0=0x0424
m324p.pid.0=0x2740

m324p.upload.tool=avrdude
m324p.upload.protocol=usbtiny
m324p.upload.maximum_size=28672
m324p.upload.maximum_data_size=2560
m324p.upload.speed=57600
m324p.upload.disable_flushing=true
m324p.upload.use_1200bps_touch=true
m324p.upload.wait_for_upload_port=true

m324p.bootloader.tool=avrdude
m324p.bootloader.low_fuses=0x62
m324p.bootloader.high_fuses=0xD9
m324p.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x0f

m324p.build.mcu=atmega324pb
m324p.build.f_cpu=1000000L
m324p.build.vid=0x0424
m324p.build.pid=0x2740
m324p.build.usb_product="Arduino m324pb"
m324p.build.board=AVR_m324pb
m324p.build.core=arduino
m324p.build.variant=standard
m324p.build.extra_flags={build.usb_flags}
```

Note that I set the upload.tool to avrdude, and the upload.protocol to usbtiny since I was using the pocket AVR programmer.

**IMPORTANT!!!**  The high fuse bit in this config also is 0xD9, instead of the default 0x99. I changed one fuse bit to disable JTAG and regain access to GPIO pins. To my knowledge Arduino wasn't setting fuse bits when uploading with the programmer, but this is an important note to take. If you need to use GPIO pins that share JTAG functionality, run the avrdude command line to set the high fuse bit appropriately. (0xD9 for me).